# Where did the EclipseLink/Maven repository go to?

Tags: maven-2, eclipselink

The link quoted on the [EclipseLink/Maven](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven) wiki ends on an Error 403 page on switch.ch. If you are redirected to a better mirror then that would already be the answer.

If not: where did the repository go to? Searching the net only reveals that EclipseLink/Maven hat a history of typos on there Wiki-Page. However all the corrected links I found end on error pages as well.

Comment: I edited the totally bogus link at the top of the [EclipseLink/Maven](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven) page to the one noted here as working. I also fixed the slightly bogus URL in the pom (got rid of the character-entity escaping). Hopefully, no one will ever look for this stackoverflow page again. (This should be a comment, but I don't have privs yet.)

Comment: Note: see also the newer question, [Where did the EclipseLink/Maven repository go to? (again)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254417/where-did-the-eclipselink-maven-repository-go-to-again)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only link I see is:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&nf=1&file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo

and it seems to works just fine, redirecting it to

http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/eclipse/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/

[image]

Comment: Thanks for mirror. It seems that this problem is indeed not a problem with EclipseLink/Maven but with the switch.ch mirror.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, now in 2011, and it seems an eclipselink/maven issue.

Answer (score 6):

The URL from that page

- http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&nf=1&file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo

works for me and redirects to

- http://eclipse.ialto.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/

However, inside a pom.xml, I had to escape the &:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>eclipselink</id>
      <url>http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&amp;nf=1&amp;file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Comment: Thanks for the POM hint - I have seen that before in my research - but one can't point that out often enough.

Answer (score 2):

Just faced the same problem today.
It appears that the URL provided on their Maven wiki page http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven works. But it works in a weird way: their repository is not indexed so if you try just to add this into pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>EclipseLink Repo</id>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

and then try to index the repository it will tell you Unable to update index for EclipseLink Repo|http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo.

But if you also include into the pom.xml this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

it will do the work and add the dependency.
Not ideal but works.

Answer (score 2):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

...

```
<repository>
    <id>EclipseLink Repo</id>
    <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
</repository>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following configuration in ivy-setting.xml worked fine for me guys:

```
<resolvers>
  <url name="eclipselink" m2compatible="true">
    <artifact pattern="http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/eclipse/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
  </url>
</resolvers>
```

Answer (score 0):

All broken. I get 404s everywhere. And the Nexus instance has not indexed the latest releases. Thank you very much for chaotic distribution managment (the project should really be relocated to Apache)

However, manual digging lead to:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
  <repository>
     <id>EclipseLink Repo</id>
     <url>http://maven.eclipse.org/nexus/service/local/repositories/Sonatype/content</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Again, this is not working 100% perfectly because Maven is not able to find dependency information.

Hmmm... maybe I should think again before using software that is obviously maintained in such an amateurish manner.