# EclipseLink Maven Repository not working correctly?

Tags: maven-2, eclipselink

I'm trying to get the EclipseLink libraries from the given Maven repositories.
I read the tips given in [Where did the EclipseLink/Maven repository go to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724841/where-did-the-eclipselink-maven-repository-go-to) on stackoverflow and tried to integrate the Maven repositories posted there into my settings.xml.

I added those links to my settings.xml and also tried my pom.xml but when trying to update the indexes I only get

```
Resource nexus-maven-repository-index.properties does not exist
```

from all of them.

Here's what I've configured in my settings.xml

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eclipseLink</id>
            <name>eclipseLink</name>
            <url>http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/eclipse/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>EclipseLink Repo</id>
            <name>eclipseLink</name>
            <url>http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?r=1&amp;nf=1&amp;file=/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled> 
            </snapshots>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>Eclipse 3</id>
            <name>eclipseLink</name>
            <url>http://eclipse.ialto.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled> 
            </snapshots>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

I'm using the m2eclipse plugin for Eclipse to integrate the dependencies.

It seemed to me that in the Question mentioned above someone else is having the same issue in 2011, but it's not answered there.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no maven, but I think the reason for this is that the repo is unindexed.
If you know what artifact you want, you can get it - but there's no index.

Comment: You really would think they could have stretched to an index.