# Where did the EclipseLink/Maven repository go to? (again)

Tags: maven, repository, eclipselink

Yes, I know, the subject [was asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724841/where-did-the-eclipselink-maven-repository-go-to), but the repository moved again. Has anybody seen it? I would be much obliged.

Comment: If it's already asked before wouldn't it be better to add a comment to that original question to have it updated?

Comment: Sorry, I could not comment on the question and giving an answer was not an option as I did not know the answer. I now did a edit-request on the question. Hope that will be granted. Can I leave this question here until the edit is granted, please?

Comment: My edit of the old question was rejected. So I think this question is valid. Anyone, please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A [quick search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=inurl:eclipselink/maven.repo) reveals a long list of mirrors, most of them returning 404s but their [cache entry](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:IO3WHFN-4lUJ:mirrors.xmission.com/eclipse/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.asm/%20inurl:eclipselink/maven.repo&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) is still viewable (for now). So it does seem like the files have been removed at the source, and rather recently too.

Here are a few mirrors that still have the files (for now):

- <s>http://linorg.usp.br/eclipse/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</s>
- <s>http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/eclipse/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</s>

---

#### Update:

[This thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg06810.html) on the eclipselink mailing list reveals something rather bizzare -- while the `maven.repo` directory is not accessible (404), subpaths  that resolves to `.jar` or `.pom` files will still work!

- This currently fails: http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/manen.repo
- But this works: http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.core/2.3.1/org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.3.1.jar

While the relevant files are still accessible, this messes up the mirroring process as well as any workflow that first checks if the repo exists. From the linked thread:

> "This of course wreaks havoc on any Nexus or Artifactory repository you may have that proxies the EclipseLink repository, as it will conclude that EclipseLink's repo is out of service even though strictly speaking it is not.  **The solution is to turn off any automatic checking of the repository and/or automated blocking of it**."

Comment: Thanks, this makes it nice and clear. I contacted the Webmaster before you gave me this useful answer and now I asked the webmaster to check this out. Who knows, this might get fixed.

Comment: But for some reason this link: http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.asm/3.3.1.v201206041142/org.eclipse.persistence.asm-3.3.1.v201206041142.pom, which should point to ASM, based by URL, points to something completely different...

Answer (score 6):

Finally there's at least a reasonable explanation on Eclipse wiki pages for why it doesn't work, see http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven. The libraries are currently only hosted in a P2 repo which plain Maven doesn't understand. Basically, you have to proxy them through via Nexus or another repo manager. The page I linked to has instructions for configuring (open source) Nexus, the premium version can read P2 repos natively.

Comment: I haven't been able to get the OSS Nexus option to work with their instructions.

Comment: Thank you for this link! Doesn't found this tiny hint on the eclipselink page in the first place!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
<repository>
    <id>eclipse</id>
    <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

As of EclipseLink 2.5.0 the EclipseLink respository is on Maven Central.

- http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.eclipse.persistence%22

The EclipseLink 2.4.2 release and the current development builds are on http://oss.sonatype.org:

```xml
<repository>
    <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
    <name>OSS Sonatype Staging</name>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/staging</url>
</repository>
```

Older releases can be found at the following repository:

```
<repository>
   <id>EclipseLink</id>
   <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
</repository>
```

**For More Information**

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Maven

Answer (score 0):

You are right, none of the Eclipse Maven repositories seem to work.

The repository at java.net does, however provide a JPA implementation: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/eclipse/persistence/javax.persistence/2.0.0/

I don't know if it's any good.

Still, the Eclipse Maven repos need to be fixed.