# Need help in Sonatype Nexus and EclipseLink Maven Repo Proxy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, eclipselink

Had cracked my head for too long with this, so I really really need help from some experts out there who has a solution for this problem.

I have installed Sonatype Nexus ver 2.0.3 and I'm having it as my development repository for JavaEE, Glassfish kind of app and have configured maven settings.xml to read from the nexus repo. Every other jar was properly downloaded and cached but everytime when it comes to jars on org.eclipse.persistence.xxx, it failed with the result:

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.3.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.0.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor:jar:2.3.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:jar:2.2.0-RC4 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa:jar:2.2.0-RC4 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen:jar:2.2.0-RC4 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.oracle:jar:2.2.0-RC4 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.antlr:jar:2.2.0-RC4 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.asm:jar:2.2.0-RC4 is missing, no dependency information available
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xxx-ejb: Could not resolve dependencies for project xxx:xxx-ejb:ejb:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.3.2, org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.0.3, org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor:jar:2.3.2, org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:jar:2.2.0-RC4, org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa:jar:2.2.0-RC4, org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen:jar:2.2.0-RC4, org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.oracle:jar:2.2.0-RC4, org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.antlr:jar:2.2.0-RC4, org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.asm:jar:2.2.0-RC4: Failure to find org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.3.2 in http://localhost:8993/nexus/content/groups/myrepo/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of MyRepo has elapsed or updates are forced -&gt; [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn &lt;goals&gt; -rf :xxx-ejb
```

Here's the way that I configure the nexus repo (open source version):

**I have created a proxy to EclipseLink:**
Repository Name: EclipseLink Maven Repository
Type: Proxy
Repository ID: eclipselink
Policy: Snapshot
Remote Storage Location: http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/
Download Remote Indexes: False
Repository Path URL: http://localhost:8993/nexus/content/repositories/ecliselink/

**As for the repo for the use of maven, I have created a group to lump the necessary repo:**
Group Name: My Repository
Group ID: myrepo
In the Ordered Group Repository Lists, I have
:- Apache Snapshots
:- Central
:- Codehaus Snapshots
:- EclipseLink Maven Repository (which is referring to the previously created EclipseLink proxy)

In my pom.xml, the snipped of dependencies are as below:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.appclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>gf-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javaee</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

In the maven settings.xml file, the mirror was defined as:

```
    <mirror>
        <id>MyRepo</id>
        <name>My Repository</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8993/nexus/content/groups/myrepo/</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
```

Just to test if one of the jars exists, I have directly call [this is not a link]http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.3.2/eclipselink-2.3.2.jar in the browser and the jar is there. But when I try to get the jar from nexus at [this is not a link]http://localhost:8993/nexus/content/repositories/eclipselink/org/eclipse/persistence/eclipselink/2.3.2/eclipselink-2.3.2.jar, its 404?!

I have updated and repaired the index but all these are to no avail. Any help is truly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I find a maven repository URL which works with "Nexus" too:

```
http://maven.eclipse.org/nexus/content/repositories/Sonatype/
```

Answer (score 1):

The root of EclipseLink repository gives a 404 error (not when you link a specific jar). This strange behaviour may be is the source of the problem and Nexus cannot index the repository.

Try to use a mirror like this:

http://linorg.usp.br/eclipse/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/

And also check this related question

[Where did the EclipseLink/Maven repository go to? (again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254417/where-did-the-eclipselink-maven-repository-go-to-again)

Comment: Hi Jordeu,

In fact, I did read through the other question on this topic before I posted. Yes, I've tried http://linorg.usp.br/eclipse/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/, repair and updated the index in myrepo group. I even down graded the eclipselink and org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor to version 2.3.0 instead of 2.3.2, but the result was still the same.

I have also tried to follow the suggestion of this page: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371255 and have tried http://maven.eclipse.org/nexus/content/repositories/Sonatype/. All of these came to the same conclusion.

Comment: The Nexus can not index this repository, because it's in the p2 format, which is not supported by nexus OpenSource. If you own a Nexus Pro you have native support for this repository format. In the OpenSource version just deactivate the download index option. You can grep all artifacts, but you cannot browse the repository on nexus.

Comment: @elton, Nexus OSS doesn't work with p2 even with deactivated indexes.

Comment: @DenysS. I thought I was using the eclipselink p2 repository like that.